# How can i clone a fieldset without displaying it to the user?

Tags: jquery

I have a fieldset here:

```
<fieldset class="pollQuestion" id="pq1">
    <legend id="legend">Q&A</legend>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="formheader" value="Question 1""></input>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" class="addQuestion" value="Add Question" />
            <input type="button" class="delQuestion" value="Remove Question" />
        </li>
        <label>Answers</label>
        <li id="answerFields">
            <input type="text" id="formanswer1" value="" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" class="addAnswer" value="Add Answer" />
            <input type="button" class="delAnswer" value="Remove Answer" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I want to clone() this because i may populate it with array contents or i may just not fill it out at all. I would like a function like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.clone = $('#pq1').clone();
});
```

but i can't get it to work for some reason

I have an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/DsVj2/4).

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos:

```
window.clone = "$('#pq1').clone()"; //remove quotes
```

`$('$clone').attr('id', 'pq'+newNum);` **should be** `$clone.attr('id', 'pq'+newNum);`

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/DsVj2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

That will create only one clone which you try to append multiple times.

But aside from that, in your Fiddle you put that in a string `window.clone = "$('#pq1').clone()"`

And then after running `$clone = window.clone` you try to use that in a jQuery object `$("$clone")`... something tells me you have no idea what you're doing...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/DsVj2/8/) is the updated Fiddle. I've managed to salvage it so that you can create new questions, but you can't remove them because you try to access `#btnDel`, which doesn't exist. Good luck...

Comment: I am very thankful that you have answered this post and have done your best to fix it but I have this working on my actual program in a similar mannar. I just need to make a fresh copy before it is edited and i thought copying it on DOM load was the best solution. This copy is after they have edited fields and wont work :(    thanks for the advice tho!

Comment: Well, there's no reason why you can't have a clone as you tried to have. However, rather than accessing the clone to put it in you should **clone the clone**, so that you always have a copy of the original stored in `window.clone`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".pollQuestion").clone().appendTo("#legend");
});
```

If this is want you are trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

In order to clone the element, you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $clone = $('#pq1').clone();
}
```

And then, in your click event, use that $clone object (don't declare it again). It won't be displayed until you attach it to DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //store in a local variable to document.ready so as not to pollute the global namespace
    var myClone = $('#pq1').clone();
    // move into document.ready so it has access to the local variable.
    $('.addQuestion').live('click', function () {
        var num = $("#pollContent fieldset.pollQuestion").length;
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
        // return a clone of the original cloned object.
        var $clone = myClone.clone();
        //remove the quotes from $clone as you want to pass the jQuery constructor a jQuery object, not a selector string.
        $($clone).attr('id', 'pq' + newNum);
        //update the question in the text box for visual confirmation that this is working.
        $($clone).find('#formheader').val('Question ' + newNum);
        // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
        $('#pq' + num).after($clone);
        // enable the "remove" button
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', '');
    });
});
```

and, of course, [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DsVj2/11/).